# Telegram Bot API Webhooks with Go, GoLang on Heroku

Tags: heroku, go, webhooks, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I use `go-telegram-bot-api` for building a Telegram Bot and deploying it on **Heroku**.

I need to set Webhooks as I used to do in Python like [in this Python case](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku).

Can't understand how to set Webhooks in `go-telegram-bot-api` without providing certificate files.

The main example contains such lines:

> If you need to use webhooks (if you wish to run on Google App Engine), you may use a slightly different method.

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/telegram-bot-api.v4"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("MyAwesomeBotToken")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    _, err = bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert("https://www.google.com:8443/"+bot.Token, "cert.pem"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    updates := bot.ListenForWebhook("/" + bot.Token)
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS("0.0.0.0:8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)

    for update := range updates {
        log.Printf("%+v\n", update)
    }
}
```

But **using Heroku for deploying** how could I listen to Webhooks without providing `pem` certificate files?

Comment: I asked this question also in Github issues to `go-telegram-bot-api` repository and got a good answer: _You'd just replace it with `go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`_ and it seems to be working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go to get the starter code.

`initTelegram()` and `webhookHandler()` are functions to study.

Once code is deployed to **Heroku**, run:

`heroku logs --tail -a <YOUR-APP-NAME>`

send some messages to the bot, you should see messages logged.

### **UPDATE 1**

Check your app URL is the same as **baseURL** variable in your code -- run `heroku info -a <YOUR-APP-NAME>` -- your URL should be equal to what Web URL is.

### **UPDATE 2**

In order to check your Telegram API Webhooks response ping this address in your browser: `https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR BOT TOKEN GOES HERE>/getWebhookInfo` where you should concatenate string `bot` and your actual Telegram Bot Token in that address string.

Optionally if you run your code not on Heroku, running `curl` from terminal could be an option according to [Official Telegram API Reference](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks):

`$ curl -F "url=https://your.domain.or.ip.com" -F "certificate=@/etc/ssl/certs/bot.pem" https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR BOT TOKEN GOES HERE>/setWebhook`

### **THE CODE:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "gopkg.in/telegram-bot-api.v4"

    _ "github.com/heroku/x/hmetrics/onload"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var (
    bot      *tgbotapi.BotAPI
    botToken = "<YOUR BOT TOKEN GOES HERE>"
    baseURL  = "https://<YOUR-APP-NAME>.herokuapp.com/"
)

func initTelegram() {
    var err error

    bot, err = tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(botToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // this perhaps should be conditional on GetWebhookInfo()
    // only set webhook if it is not set properly
    url := baseURL + bot.Token
    _, err = bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhook(url))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } 
}

func webhookHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    defer c.Request.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var update tgbotapi.Update
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &update)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // to monitor changes run: heroku logs --tail
    log.Printf("From: %+v Text: %+v\n", update.Message.From, update.Message.Text)
}

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    if port == "" {
        log.Fatal("$PORT must be set")
    }

    // gin router
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(gin.Logger())

    // telegram
    initTelegram()
    router.POST("/" + bot.Token, webhookHandler)

    err := router.Run(":" + port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I've implemented. But still the same problem. Nothing happens after a successful run on Heroku. When I try tu cURL a webhook get this json - `{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://sf-demo-bot.herokuapp.com/<my_Telegram_Token>","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":30,"last_error_date":1510981838,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found","max_connections":40}}`

Comment: Maybe Telegram API could not get OK response? I tried to add `c.String(200, "POST")` to the `webhookHandler` functions but nothing happens again.

Comment: Did you try sending message to your bot with telegram app and observe heroku logs? This is a full solution I'm sure.

Comment: @IlyaRusin can you please show the full curl command as you use it.

Comment: ... your curl json looks like your sending request to the telegram servers. I'll test some more why telegram complains about "Wrong response". Will update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159279/discussion-between-biosckon-and-ilya-rusin).

Comment: see the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159279/discussion-between-biosckon-and-ilya-rusin) above essentially this is your URL double check you giving correct heroku app URL.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Heroku for your bot, You don't need certificates. Heroku provides free SSL certificates. So, You put the URL of your app with `https` scheme and listen with a HTTP Server on the `PORT` that heroku sets for your application. See the example below to understand better.

```
func main() {
    // Create bot instance
    u := fetchUpdates(bot)

    go http.ListenAndServe(":" + PORT, nil)
}

func fetchUpdates(bot *tgbotapi.BotAPI) tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel {
    _, err = bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhook("https://dry-hamlet-60060.herokuapp.com/instagram_profile_bot/" + bot.Token))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fatalln("Problem in setting Webhook", err.Error())
    }

    updates := bot.ListenForWebhook("/instagram_profile_bot/" + bot.Token)

    return updates
}
```

Comment: Сan you, please, clarify more about `/instagram_profile_bot/` at the end of your Heroku app address? Maybe my issue is I didn't add this string? The name of this string -- is this the name of Go compiled binary? Or what?

Comment: @IlyaRusin Heroku only allows the app to run one http server. My application had a couple more endpoints for other purpose. And the `/instagram_profile_bot/` was the endpoint that I wanted my bot to use for communicating with Telegram Servers. You can replace it with `/` and it'll be just fine.

Comment: And what is `tbot.BotAPI` and `tbot.UpdateChan`?  Is it`tgbotapi.BotAPI?` And if yes - what is `UpdateChan`? I've got `undefined: tgbotapi.UpdateChan`

Comment: `tbot.BotAPI` is `tgbotapi.BotAPI` and `UpdateChan` is `UpdatesChannel` that [ListenForWebhook](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api#BotAPI.ListenForWebhook) function returns.

Comment: I've changed all this stuff but I still can't listen to my bot. I think something wrong with the library. I think I should read more carefully [https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks)